# Show that $\varphi \: : \: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}^{\ast} \to \mathbb{N} \; , \varphi(p,q)=p^2+q^2+2pq+p$ is injective.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started by assuming $\varphi(p,q)=\varphi(r,s)$ for some pairs of natural numbers. With some factorisation, I got :
\begin{equation}
(p+q+r+s)(p+q-r-s)+p-r=0
\end{equation}
I tried playing around with divisibility, but it didn't get me anywhere.
Any hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

For convenience let $a=p+q$ and $b=r+s$, and suppose that $a^2+p=b^2+r$. If $a\ne b$, assume without loss of generality that $a>b$. Then

$$r-p=a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)\ge a+b\,,$$

i.e., $r-p\ge p+q+r+s$. But then $2p+q+s\le 0$, which is impossible, so we must have $a=b$. Then $a^2=b^2$, so $p=r$, and finally $q=s$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(p+q+r+s)(p+q-r-s)$. Since the former factor is greater than $0$, the sign of this expression depends on the sign of $p+q-r-s$.

Suppose $p+q-r-s>0$. Can $(p+q+r+s)(p+q-r-s)+p-r=0$?

Suppose $p+q-r-s<0$. Can $(p+q+r+s)(p+q-r-s)+p-r=0$?

Comment: I think in all cases, we'll need the sign of $p-r$ since the left side can be positive while $p-r$ is negative to give $0$, and vice versa.

Comment: No we don't. For example, if $p+q-r-s > 0$, we have $(p+q+r+s)(p+q-r-s)+p-r \ge (p+q+r+s)+p-r=2p+r+s >0$.